# Past or present?

Tags: tense

Lets say that **X** was my student 40 years ago.

I want to emphasize that at this moment 1) I still consider him as a student of mine; 2) he still treats me as his teacher.

Can I say, *“X **is** my student … about 40 years ago”*?

Comment: Yes. We'd probably say something like, "X is my student...from about forty years ago." Then the other person would act surprised and respond, "You still call X your student?" And you'd say, "Yes. My students will always be my students." Is this what you mean?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang No, not from about .... . I taught X for a year only and that was forty years ago. We maintain a good (friend-like) relationship from then on.

Comment: *emphasis* is a noun; *emphasize* is a verb. So *you want to emphasize*.

Comment: @user178049 Emphasize. My bad.

Comment: Just to double-check: you are not **currently teaching** X, and the last time they were actively taught by you was 40 years ago, but your relationship is still that of student-teacher?

Comment: @SteveES 1) That is correct that I am NOT currently teaching X. 2) correct, the last lesson was 40 years ago. 3) The current relationship is friends but X respects me as a teacher and I want to tell others that X was taught by me 40 years ago and I am still consider him as my student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately what you propose doesn't imply the meaning you would like, and as written, it is not grammatically correct. As Teacher KSHuang said, you could say:

> X is my student...from about forty years ago.

but it would probably require further explanation for the listener to understand what you meant.

A better way to phrase it might be something like the following:

> I still think of X as my student, even though I last taught him/her 40 years ago.

Or, swapping the order over:

> I last taught X 40 years ago, but I still think of him/her as my student.

(You could replace "think of him/her as" by "treat him/her like" if there are more obvious actions on your part treating them like they are still your student.)

Or possibly (if this is true):

> X still calls me "teacher", even though he/she was last in my classroom 40 years ago.

You could replace "teacher" with some other teaching-related title or epithet if it is more appropriate/true. For example, in the UK, a male teacher may be called "sir" by his pupils, but most other people (i.e. those who are not teachers) would not be called "sir". You could also replace "classroom" with some other teaching-related space if that is more appropriate, such as "lecture theatre".

Your original phrasing might sound more natural if you were making some judgement on them. For example:

> X is still my favourite student, even though he/she left my classroom 40 years ago.

This phrasing would imply that you are still "teaching" X, but not in a formal way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the present indicative tense with a time in the past.

Instead, use the present perfect.

> X has been my student for forty years.

This says that the relationship began forty years ago and continues through the present day.

Comment: How to include the idea that the actual teacher-student relationship only lasted for 1 year (which was 40 years ago)?

Comment: If you want to distinguish between when he was *actually* your student, and when you *considered* him like a student, then I think you need two separate clauses, as SteveES suggests.